# What is the power series of the given Maclaurin series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

The given series is:
$$x+2x^2+x^3+2x^4+x^5+2x^6+....$$
Now I can see that the sum starts at $n=0$ and that is closely follows the common series $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

What I have so far is: 
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}x^{n+1}$$
What I am having trouble with is the $2$ that alternates terms, I see that it is only present on the even exponent terms and that it must have an $(-1)^n$ term in the sum but I can't figure it out

Comment: Maybe you could construct it as a sum of two sum terms? The other would indeed be $x^n$, but the other would add to every other term ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots=\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$$and that therefore the sum of your series is$$\frac x{1-x}+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}=\frac{2x^2+x}{1-x^2}.$$

Comment: When you say "therefore", what steps did you take to find the sum of the series?

Comment: \begin{align}x+2x^2+x^3+2x^2+\cdots&=(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots)+(x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8+\cdots)\\&=\frac x{1-x}+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm still wondering, is the sum I have in my question at least partly correct or close the the final answer?

Comment: No, it is not correct, since the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1}$ is not the series $x+2x^2+x^3+2x^4+\cdots$.

Comment: I know that, but is the $x^{n+1}$ part correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is $(x+2x^2)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots)$